What are the meaning of some of these small letters in the Torah
BH
Hi, I remember — correct me if I’m wrong — that the aleph of the first word of Vayikra is small because Moshe’s humility because he said how can I be written at the beginning of such a holy book so therefore Hashem made the first aleph small. (Little Midrash Says on Vayikra)
Similarly in Gen. 2:4 ele toldot hashamaim ve haaretz behibaram etc. The hay in behibaram is small I heard because malchut is lowered down to here to this lowest world because Hashem uses it to bring life down here even though this world is the darkest out of all the worlds (Kuntrus Umayan discourse 5 I believe)
I know there is a book called sefer קטן וגדול by Rav Tzvi Ron, although are there any other english sources whether chassidic or kabbalistic that explain the other small letters though like in like Vayikra 6:2 and like Berashit 27:46? What do they mean here? Also what are the sources for the explanation of all the other ones like in sefer קטן וגדול although in English if there is?

https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13809-small-and-large-letters

There is a relatively short book in Hebrew כתרי אותיות which compiles many sources https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/144684/36610

In Hebrew, Torah Sheleimah Vol 39 - תורה שלמה - כט - is dedicated to this subject. Can be downloaded from https://hebrewbooks.org/51444

In English with links to other explanations: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4765997/jewish/Why-the-Big-and-Small-Letters-in-the-Torah.htm

@DannySchoemann:  I suppose you meant Torah Sheleimah Vol 29
